# Is there a literal-string version of "looking-at"?

Tags: regular-expressions, string

The function `looking-at` matches a regex, in some cases however I want to match against a literal string. While `(looking-at (regexp-quote text))` works, it seems like there might be a way to do this that bypasses regex entirely.

Without this I end up using `buffer-substring` can comparing the string, but it seems as if there might be a more efficient way to do this as there is some room for error with bounds checking for e.g.

Comment: There's no obligation to provide such info, but I'm curious, and it just might help with the answers you get (dunno): What's your concern about using `regexp-quote` to get literal string matching? What's the efficiency concern, e.g., for what kind of use case do you care about this efficiency difference (assuming there is a difference)? Also, do you need `looking-at` in your use case, or just `looking-at-p`? Again, just curious - I'd use `(looking-at (regexp-quote text))` until/unless in some particular case I found it led to some relevant problem.

Comment: I'm looking to write a package that syntax highlights comments based on their contents, see this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/14pyf8x since this runs as part of font-locking I want it to be as fast as possible, so if there is a quick way to match literal strings, that would be preferable.

Comment: So I guess you know the strings you'll encounter ahead of time, so there's no possibility that they contain anything regexp-relevant... I still can't imagine a case where any optimization here is called for - especially seeing the example you show in that linked Reddit post. Remember: font-lock is regexp-based, and **lots** of font-lock patterns are not regexp-relevant (i.e., plain string matching). And font-lock happens even in situations where speed is important - and it happens repeatedly, all the time. IOW, so far, I can't guess the use case that calls for avoiding `regexp-quote` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
(search-forward "string" (+ (point) (length "string")) t)
```

but I'm not convinced that would be significantly faster than using
`looking-at-p` plus `regexp-quote` like @Drew suggests.

Here's what some quick benchmarks show for me:

```
(benchmark-run-compiled 10000000
  (save-excursion
    (search-forward "string" (+ (point) (length "string")) t)))
=> (15.868925050000001 35 8.100802817000044)

(benchmark-run-compiled 10000000
  (save-excursion
    (search-forward "string" (+ (point) 6) t)))
=> (15.703928073000002 35 7.964655790999984)

(benchmark-run-compiled 10000000
  (looking-at-p (regexp-quote "string")))
=> (4.905593267 0 0.0)

(benchmark-run-compiled 10000000
  (looking-at-p "string"))
=> (4.648821162 0 0.0)

(benchmark-run-compiled 10000000
  (looking-at (regexp-quote "string")))
=> (4.6541677340000005 0 0.0)

(benchmark-run-compiled 10000000
  (looking-at "string"))
=> (3.552957473 0 0.0)
```

so I'd say `looking-at` or `looking-at-p` are the functions to use.

Comment: It's highly possible that `looking-at-p` is slower, because it needs to parse the regexp. `search-forward` is a more specific function; it knows that its argument is a literal string instead of regexp, which means it gets more information than `looking-at-p`. When the situation is more specific (more information is known), we can usually choose a better algorithm.

Comment: Anyway, I can't see a reason to use regexp-related functions here.

Comment: @shynur, I was obliquely asking someone to go and test the actual difference :-)

Comment: *Note:* If the string is long and it doesn't match, then this is NOT performant at all. It systematically runs down the entire string to get its length. Imagine that the first character doesn't match and the string is 4 MB long... Maybe such code makes sense for your (OP's) particular context; dunno. But that would be a corner case, not a general one.

Comment: Sure, in real code you're memoize the length. In any case, quick and dirty benchmarking suggests that `looking-at-p` beats `search-forward` here by a factor of 4 at least. I'll update the answer.